# Regarding DateTime Format Issue for exported record in csv file + C#.NET

Tags: c#, csv

I am facing one strange issue while exporting DateTime record in CSV File.
I have chosen DateTime format as "DD MON YYYY". I can see DateTime records are formatted correctly and displayed as expected in grid (e.g: `05 Feb 2016 12:46 AM`). When I tried to export same records in CSV file, I can see DateFormat has changed and exported as `2/5/2016 0:46`.

I verified my code and found that DateTime records are exported correctly (keeping the same DateTime format as seen in grid). On further verification, I can see that exported DateTime records are decorated according to the user's local system short date & time format.

Here is an example:

[image]

Note: When same records exported in Excel/Pdf, it's working as expected.

How do get the same behavior in CSV?

**Adding more details here -**

When I open this 'csv' file, I can see that 'Date Joined' column is displaying value as 21/03/2016 15:40:27 which is NOT correct. If I open the same file in Notepad by right click on it, I can see proper date format as 21 Mar 2016 3:40:27 PM which is same as displayed in grid. Please advice.

---

### Code

```
  public MemoryStream StringToMemoryStream
   (Encoding encoding, string source)
  {

  var content = encoding.GetBytes(source);
  var tempMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(content);
  var csvFilePath = SaveStream(tempMemoryStream, "Sample.csv");

  return tempMemoryStream;
 }

 private string SaveStream(MemoryStream ms, string filename)
 {
   var actualFilePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),   
           filename);
   var outStream = File.OpenWrite(actualFilePath);

   ms.WriteTo(outStream);
   outStream.Flush();
   outStream.Close();

   return actualFilePath;
 }
```

**Note:** Here is the value for input string "source" parameter that's used in **StringToMemoryStream** -

Customer Id,First Name,Last Name,Date Joined,Address,City,Country,Zip Code
CS0001,John Smith,Andrews,21 Mar 2016 3:40:27 PM,"100 Cheryl Drive",Jersey City,USA,08830

Comment: Please post the code as text in the question. Please read the help on how to format code in the edit view.

Comment: Please add the code to your question. You will find an **edit** link below your question. Do not post the code in the comment, it is unreadable.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Updated code in my original post. Please verify and advice on this.

Comment: Any resolution/guidance for the above issue will be really helpful.

Comment: @sukanta, could you solve this?